# ¿Como hacer para obtener la informacion de un item de un listView haciendo click en el?

Tags: android-studio, listview, botón, onclicklistener

Tengo un ListView con un boton y quiero que al pulsarlo se recojan los datos de ese item a un metodo en una clase distinta , he probado con el metodo **setOnItemClickListener** pero no me funciona

El codigo Java de la activity es este:

```
public class InicioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lvServicios;
    Button btnAceptar;
    ArrayList<Servicio> servicios = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        lvServicios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvServicios);
        servicios = Conexion.ObtenerListaServicios();
        AdaptadorServicios adaptador = new AdaptadorServicios(this,servicios);
        lvServicios.setAdapter(adaptador);

        lvServicios.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String ref = servicios.get(position).getReferencia(); 
                Conexion.ActualizarEstado(ref);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿No entra al evento o no te regresa los datos que deseas?

Comment: Que error te da?